# kdb conditional update and select in one query

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I can do this:

```
x:([]v: 4 2; w: 10 100)
x: update z:`test from x where v = 4
x
```

But i'd really like to be able to do the conditional update and select all in one hit.  something like

```
select v, w, (select `test from x where v = v) from z
```

Is this possible in kdb?

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
update z:?[v=4;`test;`] from x
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the vector conditional if what you're looking for?

```
q)select v,w,z:?[v=4;`test;`] from x
v w   z
----------
4 10  test
2 100
```

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional